# Parsing JSON data array in Unity from a web API using SimpleJSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, parsing, httpwebrequest

Hi thanks for taking time to look at my issue.
I am using SimpleJSON to parse a stream of data coming from https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1327025/fields/1.json?results=1
specifically trying to get to "field1" which is inside "feeds".

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using SimpleJSON;
using TMPro;

public class onLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text temperatureData;

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using SimpleJSON;
using TMPro;

public class onLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text temperatureData;

    public void GetJsonData()
    {
        StartCoroutine(RequestWebService());
        Debug.Log("test");
    }

    IEnumerator RequestWebService()
    {
        string jsonString = "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1327025/fields/1.json?results=1";
        Debug.Log(jsonString);

        using (UnityWebRequest webData = UnityWebRequest.Get(jsonString))
        {
            yield return webData.SendWebRequest();
            if (webData.isNetworkError || webData.isHttpError)
            {
                print("---------------- ERROR ----------------");
                print(webData.error);
            }
            else
            {
                if (webData.isDone)
                {
                    JSONNode jsonData = JSON.Parse(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(webData.downloadHandler.data));

                    if (jsonData == null)
                    {
                        print("---------------- NO DATA ----------------");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("---------------- JSON DATA ----------------");
                        print("jsonData.Count:" + jsonData.Count);

                        temperatureData.text = jsonData["feeds\field1"];
                        Debug.Log(temperatureData.text);
        }
    }
            }}}}
```

My code seems to work fine, as in I get the "jsonData.Count" to work (which comes up as 2). I am assuming that its reading the "channel" and "feeds". But it pops out as null.

How do I place the key and item inside jsonData to get to field1 ?
Thanks

Comment: Won't `jsonData [ "feeds" ] [ 0 ] [ "field1" ]` will give the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

The simple JSON basically works like a **dictionary** with single keywords ... you can't just pass a *path* to it.

What you want is

- first accessing the `feeds`
- it is an array so get an element .. probably the first one?
- of that element finally access the `field1`

So something like

```
temperatureData.text = jsonData["feeds"][0]["field1"].Value;
```